# How to remove tuple from list in a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, tuples

I have function that should determine the best way to fill a stack with a capacity of 200.
requirements are:

- small items that still fit should be placed first
- if two items have the same size, the item with the highest price should be placed first.

```
capacity = 200

dairy_items=[('p1', 10, 3), ('p2', 13, 5),
             ('p3', 15, 2), ('p4', 26, 2),
             ('p5', 18, 6), ('p6', 25, 3),
             ('p7', 20, 4), ('p8', 10, 5),
             ('p9', 15, 4), ('p10', 12, 7),
             ('p11', 19, 3), ('p12', 27, 6),
             ('p13', 16, 4), ('p14', 23, 5),
             ('p15', 14, 2), ('p16', 23, 5), 
             ('p17', 12, 7), ('p18', 11, 3),
             ('p19', 16, 5), ('p20', 11, 4)]
```

the first tuple element is the unique product id, the second is the product size and the third is the price

So I created this function. I only have one problem. The first thing that is stacked is product p8, so this one needs to be removed from dairy_items so that the function does not select that value again as it is already used. I tried this with dairy_items.remove(), but it doesn't work. Are there other methods I can use or do I simply not use it the right way.

```
def shelving(dairy_items):
    filled = 0
    worth = 0
    shelves = []
    while filled <= capacity:
        smallest_product = math.inf
        most_expensive_product = 0
        
        for productNr in range(len(dairy_items)):
            if dairy_items[productNr][1] < smallest_product:
                smallest_product = dairy_items[productNr][1]
                most_expensive_product = dairy_items[productNr][2]
                productID = dairy_items[productNr][0]
  
            elif smallest_product == dairy_items[productNr][1]:
                if dairy_items[productNr][2] > most_expensive_product:
                    smallest_product = dairy_items[productNr][1]
                    productID = dairy_items[productNr][0]
        filled = filled + smallest_product
        worth = worth + most_expensive_product
        shelves.append(productID)
        dairy_items.remove((productID, smallest_product, most_expensive_product))
       
    return (shelves,filled,worth)
```

Comment: Try making another copy of diary_items and do the removing part there. Since you are iterating with the length of list and making changes in the list, you may run into error. Better make a separate copy to do the job.

Comment: Added some extra improvements to my answer to help you avoid this kind of issue in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `elif` block doesn't assign `most_expensive_product`. Therefore you can have a `most_expensive_product` that was assigned in the `if` block and a `smallest_product` and `productID` assigned in the `elif`. This results in you constructing a tuple in the `remove` call which never actually existed in the first place so cannot be removed.

You can solve this by adding an assignment in the `elif` - assuming this is your desire behaviour.

```
most_expensive_product = dairy_items[productNr][2]
```

I'm a little confused by your variable names as `most_expensive_product` doesn't seem to be the most expensive product, but rather the price of the smallest product (or the more expensive if there are multiple smallest items).

If my assumptions about what you are trying to do are correct you'd be much better served with a for loop so you avoid mucking about with indexes and reconstructing the tuple. For example the below appears to do what you were intending:

```
def shelving(dairy_items):
    filled = 0
    worth = 0
    shelves = []
    while filled <= capacity:
        chosen_product = dairy_items[0]

        for product in dairy_items:
            if product[1] < chosen_product[1]:
                chosen_product = product

            elif chosen_product[1] == product[1]:
                if product[2] > chosen_product[2]:
                    chosen_product = product
        filled = filled + chosen_product[1]
        worth = worth + chosen_product[2]
        shelves.append(chosen_product[0])
        dairy_items.remove(chosen_product)

    return (shelves, filled, worth)
```

However, this still has one problem which your original code had; it will overfill the shelf as it only checks capacity at the start of the loop. This could be fixed by adding a check at the end like so:

```
def shelving(dairy_items):
    filled = 0
    worth = 0
    shelves = []
    while filled <= capacity:
        chosen_product = dairy_items[0]

        for product in dairy_items:
            if product[1] < chosen_product[1]:
                chosen_product = product

            elif chosen_product[1] == product[1]:
                if product[2] > chosen_product[2]:
                    chosen_product = product
        if filled + chosen_product[1] <= capacity:
            filled = filled + chosen_product[1]
            worth = worth + chosen_product[2]
            shelves.append(chosen_product[0])
            dairy_items.remove(chosen_product)
        else:
            break

    return (shelves, filled, worth)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the variable most_expensive_product is indeed the more expensive one if products have the same size. The preference goes to the more expensive one.

Answer (score 0):

There were some silly mistakes in my code. I changed a few things and the following worked out for me.

```
def shelving(dairy_items):
    filled = 0
    worth = 0
    shelves = []
    while filled <= capacity:
        smallest_product = math.inf
        most_expensive_product = 0
        for productNr in range(len(dairy_items)):
            if dairy_items[productNr][1] < smallest_product:
                smallest_product = dairy_items[productNr][1]
                most_expensive_product = dairy_items[productNr][2]
                productID = dairy_items[productNr][0]
            elif smallest_product == dairy_items[productNr][1]:
                if dairy_items[productNr][2] > most_expensive_product:
                    smallest_product = dairy_items[productNr][1]
                    productID = dairy_items[productNr][0]
                    most_expensive_product = dairy_items[productNr][2]
        dairy_items.remove((productID, smallest_product, most_expensive_product))
        if filled + smallest_product >= 200:
            break
        filled = filled + smallest_product
        worth = worth + most_expensive_product
        shelves.append(productID)
        
       
    return (shelves, filled , worth)
```